# How to import a service for testing locally in Django using the shell?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to debug a service in Django using the shell. I ran the following in `make shell`:

```
from domains.coffee.services import CoffeeService
```

However, I got

> Apps aren't loaded yet.

Can someone please help me to import a service to test its functionalities locally?

I tried running `make shell`, and importing the service into the shell, but was unable to.

Comment: ah, just realized this works with make django-shell...